# How to split a Chinese string by character?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string containing mostly chinese characters, like so:

```
string sentence = "我想找到从夏洛特飞往拉斯维加斯，让站在圣路易斯";
```

How can I split the sentence by character?  Ultimately, I want to be able to take my string, and write it to a file with each character being on its own line, like so:

```
我
想
找
到
从
夏
洛
特
飞
往
拉
斯
维
加
斯
，
让
站
在
圣
路
易
斯
```

I tried doing this:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char character in sentence.ToCharArray())
{
    s.Append(character + '\n');
}
string output = s.ToString();

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.Write(output);
writer.Close();
```

...but for whatever reason, instead of writing chinese characters, it writes

```
   29252242105020184228092794129315391442445825299260413251021162260416530235763314592232222317363452614126041
```

...to the file instead.
However, doing

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("text.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.Write(sentence);
writer.Close();
```

...does successfully write the Chinese sentence to the file, so I do know it shouldn't be a problem with how I'm writing to the file.

Comment: +1. Interesting problem because the tendency is to assume it's an encoding issue, but it's actually much simpler (per answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem may be that 
    (character + '\n');
is being interpreted as an integer. Perhaps trying adding a cast to that line or making two seperate appends like so:

```
s.Append(character);
s.Append('\n');
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  The `+` operator on `char`s doesn't do string concatenation.  Instead, it implicitly converts the `char`s to `int`s and adds them.  For example, `'A' + 'B' == 65 + 66 == 131`.

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the problem!  (...although StackOverflow won't let me select an answer for another 9 minutes...)

Comment: Could do `character + "\n"` or `character + Environment.NewLine` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var sentence = "我想找到从夏洛特飞往拉斯维加斯，让站在圣路易斯";
        var chars = sentence.ToCharArray();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            foreach (var c in chars)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(c);
            }

            writer.Close();
        }
```

Works fine for me